# upload file via curl

Tags: php, curl, permissions, upload

I try to upload file via curl in php,
this is my sample code

```
set_time_limit(0);
$url = 'http://localhost/curltest/upload.php';
$field_name = 'file'; 
if (isset($_FILES['file']))
{
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array("$field_name"=>"@".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
}
```

I set permission to 777,but it doesn't work.
where is the problem?
(it doesn't show any result)

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the result? What's the symptom?

Comment: What tells you that it does not work?

Comment: why not just use `move_uploaded_file()` or lookup the example #2 here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a problem here : `$_FILES['file'['tmp_name']` it should be `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` or something like this. You forget to close the ['file' bracket

Comment: it's problem in entering code in stackoverflow , but my code in localhost is true

Comment: Ok then follow Larence Cherone advices look for move_uploaded_file